# Google drive sync folder on your computer fills my disk up

Tags: hard-drive, google-drive-file-stream, google-drive-for-desktop

I wanted to make a backup of a specific folder on my laptop, which mounts a small SSD disk with 60 GB of free space remaining.

I installed Google Drive and configured it for file streaming, and I added the local folder (more than 100 GB) to sync.

I did not expect my disk to get full, causing both GDrive and other apps to stop functioning until a reboot.

So here is the thing: when I restart, the disk space goes back to normal, but after a hour or two of syncing the problem arises again.

I am also afraid of data loss due to software crashes, so I would like to know why this happens, and if it is impossible to sync a large folder when the laptop is short on space.

Comment: If you wish to play with lots of big files, you need to get a bigger disk.  Computers that came with tiny disks are a BIG problem for most users.

Comment: Note that syncing goes both ways. Is it possible that it's syncing your Trash folder to the local disk? Or perhaps the automatically selected standard folders like My Documents or Photos folders?

Comment: No, I was syncing only a specific folder on this device

Comment: You can try finding large, lesser used files and move them to a secondary USB drive. That may help. Ultimately, you need a larger drive (500 GB for normal use; 1 TB for large files and large use)

Comment: Is there any risk that Google drive caused data loss when lacking space? I think it does NOT move files around, just copy to the hidden temp upload folder and sync, right?

Comment: Whether Google Drive loss data depends on how you used it. In regular use Google Drive does not loose data.

Comment: Instead of [tag:google-drive] use [tag:google-drive-filestream]. According to the tag excerpt, the first is for questions about a desktop client that is deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

> small SSD disk with 60 GB of free space remaining. I added the local
> folder (more than 100 GB) to sync.

Your main drive is much too small to do what you are trying to do.

And despite what you may read, Windows works best on one drive. A lot of Windows (exclusive of Documents) is not readily movable somewhere else.

You only real hope here is a much bigger drive:  500 GB minimum for large scale file streaming.

Note:  I passed the 500 GB minimum a decade ago and now my own minimum on any machine of my own is 1 TB SSD.